# json array character value ascending and descending order typescript

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an array like the following:

```
var homes = [  
 {
   "h_id": "3","city": "Dallas","state": "YYYY","zip": "75201","price": "162500"
 },
 {
   "h_id": "4","city": "CA","state": "ZZZZ","zip": "90210","price": "319250"
 }, 

 {
  "h_id": "5","city": "New York","state": "AAAA","zip": "00010","price": "962500"
 },

 {
  "h_id": "5","city": "New York","state": "CCCC","zip": "00010","price": "962500"
 }
];
```

I need to sort it so i can be able to check state in both ascending and descending order,

The result needed as following:

```
var homes = [ 
{
 "h_id": "5", "city": "New York", "state": "AAAA", "zip": "00010", "price": "962500" 
 },
 { 
  "h_id": "5", "city": "New York", "state": "CCCC", "zip": "00010", "price": "962500" 
 },
 { 
  "h_id": "3", "city": "Dallas", "state": "YYYY", "zip": "75201", "price": "162500" 
 },
 { 
  "h_id": "4", "city": "CA", "state": "ZZZZ", "zip": "90210", "price": "319250" 
 },
];
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: whats the priority ?

Comment: json array character ascending and descending

Comment: Please consider rewriting your question so we can better understand what you are looking for. Also consider posting what you have attempted so far in order to solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
homes = homes .sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.state);
});
```

You can use city,h_id etc in place of state

Comment: thnx it's perfectly work,pls can u explain  elaborate